# ggplot and sf - category by color

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

when plotting this very simple `sf` multipoint feature

```
gm.multipoints <- st_multipoint(rbind(
  c(0.1, 51.5),
  c(11.3, 44.4),
  c(-3.7, 40.4),
  c(2.3, 48.8)
))

df.attr <- data.frame(
  name = c('London', 'Bologna', 'Madrid', 'Paris'),
  temperature = c(21,31,29,25),
  language = c('English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'French')
)

gmsf.multipoint <- st_sf(df.attr,geometry = st_sfc(gm.multipoints,crs = 'EPSG:4326'))
```

with `ggplot` as

```
ggplot(gmsf.multipoint) +
  geom_sf(aes(color=name))
```

I get the same color for all cities as in the attached figure. Why isn't each city colored differently?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the excellent `{tidygeocoder}` package to look up the coordinates of cities as points / and not as multipoint, which will figure as a single row, as other users noted.

The proposed call will geocode the cities by name while keeping the non-spatial ("data") information - language, temperature - intact.

It uses the Nominatim (i.e. Open Street Map) geocoder, and for smallish number of objects (like these 4 cities) is very quick & user friendly.

The plotting part is unchanged.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

df.attr <- data.frame(
  name = c('London', 'Bologna', 'Madrid', 'Paris'),
  temperature = c(21,31,29,25),
  language = c('English', 'Italian', 'Spanish', 'French')
)

cities <- df.attr %>% 
  tidygeocoder::geocode(address = name,
                        return_input = T) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

ggplot(cities) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = name))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because `st_multipoint` is what it says, a (one single) feature composed of multiple points. What you want is one point per row which is different. If you look at your dataframe (print it by example) you'll see that geometry is repeated.

```
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -3.7 ymin: 40.4 xmax: 11.3 ymax: 51.5
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
     name temperature language                       geometry
1  London          21  English MULTIPOINT ((0.1 51.5), (11...
2 Bologna          31  Italian MULTIPOINT ((0.1 51.5), (11...
3  Madrid          29  Spanish MULTIPOINT ((0.1 51.5), (11...
4   Paris          25   French MULTIPOINT ((0.1 51.5), (11...
```

Unfortunately there isn't as far as I know such a function in `sf` package.

Using following custom function you'll be able to create multiple separate points.

```
# build POINT list (not a MULTIPOINT) from multiples coordinates
# adapted from sf:::st_as_sf.data.frame
st_points <- function(x, y=NULL, dim="XYZ", crs=NA_crs_) {
  if(is.data.frame(x))
    x <- as.matrix(x)
  if(!is.null(y))
    x <- cbind(x,y)
  if(!is.matrix(x))
    stop("Need a matrix!")
  structure(sf:::points_rcpp(x, dim),
    n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, crs = sf:::make_crs(crs), bbox = structure(c(xmin = min(x[[1]],
      na.rm = TRUE), ymin = min(x[[2]], na.rm = TRUE),
      xmax = max(x[[1]], na.rm = TRUE), ymax = max(x[[2]],
        na.rm = TRUE)), class = "bbox"), class = c("sfc_POINT",
          "sfc"), names = NULL)
}

gm.multipoints <- st_points(rbind(
  c(0.1, 51.5),
  c(11.3, 44.4),
  c(-3.7, 40.4),
  c(2.3, 48.8)
))

# rest of your code
```

By printing and plotting we get what we expect.

```
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0.1 ymin: 11.3 xmax: 0.1 ymax: 11.3
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
     name temperature language          geometry
1  London          21  English  POINT (0.1 51.5)
2 Bologna          31  Italian POINT (11.3 44.4)
3  Madrid          29  Spanish POINT (-3.7 40.4)
4   Paris          25   French  POINT (2.3 48.8)
```

[image: Expected plot]